# Javascript scroll function on my checkout page in Woocommerce not moving to the right place

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

On my checkout page in Woocommerce I want to move the coupon link from the top of the page to the order review box between subtotal and payment methods with my own translation. I want the coupon box to open at the bottom of the page and scroll there automatically. I managed moving the link and having the box to open at the bottom of the page by finding the code below Googling (source: https://www.sellwithwp.com/move-the-woocommerce-coupon-field/):

The problem is: The page scrolls too far to the bottom. I want it to stop at the discount box. The box opens below the checkout form when the voucher link is clicked. This is the URL to the page: https://www.shopamerica.nl/afrekenen/ (you need something above €20 in the cart,like https://www.shopamerica.nl/product/hersheys-kisses-milk-chocolate-party-bag-113-kg/)
It must be in this line:

```
$( "html, body" ).animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, "slow" );
```

I googled and searched on this site, thought I found solutions with a div box. But I don’t get it to work. Thank you for your help.

Code to move form link and box to the bottom

```
// move form link check out to bottom
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' );
```

Code to move form link order review box

```
// rename coupon message on checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'sww_add_wc_order_email_images', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_message_on_checkout() {
    return 'Heb je een voucher?' . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Click here to enter your code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_message_on_checkout' );
// rename the coupon field on the checkout page
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_checkout( $translated_text, $text, $text_domain ) {
    // bail if not modifying frontend woocommerce text
    if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }
    if ( 'Coupon code' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = 'voucher';

    } elseif ( 'Apply Coupon' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Vouchercode toepassen';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_checkout', 10, 3 );
// show form link in order review section
function sa_show_coupon_js() {
    wc_enqueue_js( '
        $( "a.showcoupon" ).parent().hide();

        $( "body" ).bind( "updated_checkout", function() {
            $( "#show-coupon-form" ).click( function() {
                $( ".checkout_coupon" ).show();
                $( "html, body" ).animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()},            "slow" );
                return false;
            } );
        } );
    ');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'sa_show_coupon_js' );
/**
 * Show a coupon link above the order details.
**/
function sa_show_coupon() {
    echo '<p class="voucher_sa"> Heb je een voucher? <a href="#" id="show-coupon-form">Klik hier om de code in te vullen</a>.</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'sa_show_coupon' );
```

Comment: The line you're showing explicitly scrolls to the bottom of the document. If you want it to scroll to some element instead, you'll have to make it do literally that (the jQuery documentation, and also google and stackoverflow search, should cover the "how do I do that?" part).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your super fast response. I got this far too. The line that specifically scrolls to the bottom is the only one that actually worked so I left it in place for now because it was better then the top. I maybe too new but I tried many solutions I found googling and in stackoverflow but with each attempt nothing literally happened. So that was the point I posted this question. It wasn't because I was not willing to Google I just could not get it to work with solutions I found. Would be great if you or somebody else could point me a bit more in the right direction. Thank you :-)